# Scripting and searching through the results (Forms)

Tags: javascript, html

There is [this](http://dreamscholarsleague.com/results.html) website in which the results of some competition are there, but the thing is that I forgot my hall ticket number If I enter name in there ("Test") and put say "9245" in the hall ticket number it shows the result but of that hall ticket number it doesnt do anything of the name. But the result is not mine, I know that my hall ticket number is of 4 digits. I was wondering if I could program something so that it tests for all 4 digit numbers and check if the name shown in the result is `=="Daksh"` if so return the hall ticket number. Is this possible? Also, I checked the source of the page and found a linked `http://dreamscholarsleague.com/js/results.js`

Can I do something so that I can find my hall ticket number?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
function check(i){
    $.post('http://dreamscholarsleague.com/php/results.php', JSON.stringify({ hallticket:i, name: 'dfd'}))
     .done(function(d){
        try{
            var result = JSON.parse(d)[0];
            var name = result["studentName"].toLowerCase();
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log("Parse error for "+i);
            if(i<9999)check(i+1);
            return;
        }
        if(name.indexOf("daksh")!==-1){
            console.log("Found! " + result);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Checked "+i);
            if(i<9999)check(i+1);
        }

     })
     .fail(function(){
        console.log("[post] error "+i);
        if(i<9999)check(i+1);
    });
}

check(1000);
```

Comment: Where do I run this? I was thinking this could be done by putting something in address bar... how to run this?

Comment: run from chrome/firefox console (press `F12`)

Comment: +1 for the approach. But is not practical and will not work ;)

Comment: Select _console_ and run; But it seems u need to do this one by one; it wont work inside a loop (i.e. 1000 to 9999). Server seems to reject. ... refactoring it

Comment: @mshsayem So it wont work :( ?

Comment: @juvian Yours is giving an error

Comment: Refactored to work without spamming the server at a time

Comment: @mshsayem It just checks 8 and then gives error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e VM93:6
(anonymous function) VM93:6
l jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
c.fireWith jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
T jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
r

Comment: Modified to handle errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could do someting like this if you can use jquery:

```
function make_ajax(name,hallticket, max){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://dreamscholarsleague.com/php/results.php",
      type: "post",
      data: '{"name":"'+name+'","hallticket":"'+hallticket+'"}',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(data){
          var name = data[0]["studentName"];
          console.log(name,hallticket);
            if(name.indexOf("Daksh")!==-1){
                alert("Found! " + hallticket);
            }
      },
       complete:function(){
           console.log(hallticket)
           if(hallticket<max) make_ajax(name,hallticket+1,max)
       }
      });
}

    make_ajax("Daksh",1000, 2500);
    make_ajax("Daksh",2500, 5000);
    make_ajax("Daksh",5000, 7500);
    make_ajax("Daksh",7500, 10000);
```

Will take a good while though.

Comment: You can run it with run from chrome/firefox console or here:http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/7q6YG/1/ . You need to open console to check result though

Comment: edited code, you need to run it in chrome/firefox console on the webpage for it to work

Comment: The script before doest work, uploaded faster working script, and will alert if found instead of console.log() so its easier to notice

Comment: I am still not able to get my number

Comment: Well, I checked the results and your name wasnt there : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=GHm1Yfw6
Not sure if you have another ticketnumber or the website stopped working midway